# Where to find error in bibliography: "finished with exit code 2" bibtex

Tags: bibtex, kile

I obtained a `finished with exit code 2` using kile when compiling the bibliography. I presume there is an error in how I've written the bibliography (.bib) file.

Is there a sort of debugger which indicates what is actually the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to open the file .blg that was produced. In that file there are all the indications about the compilation of the bibliography and, if any, the detailed description of the errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: there is no blg file ... not an answer